# Script running incorrectly for email sent when specific column has data

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the below script that is running but marks the "Email_Sent" column for every row (all 1000), I would like it to only send an email if Column A, B or C has an entry. (This is copied from the first sheet if someone marks a Yes in a specific column) and only if the Sent_Email column is blank as well.

```
        function sendEmails()
        {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Email"));
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
var data = dataRange.getValues();
 for (var i = 1; i < data.length; ++i) 
{
   var rowData = data[i];
   var emailAddress = rowData[1];
var recipient = rowData[0];
var message1 = rowData[3];
var message2 = rowData[4];
var message3 = rowData[5];
var message4 = rowData[6];
var message5 = rowData[7];
var emailSent = rowData[9];
var message = 'Hi ' + recipient + ',\n\n' + message1 + ' ' + message2 + 
 ',\n\n' + message3 + ',\n' + message4 + ',\n' + message5;
var subject = 'Medical Questionairre Check';
if (emailSent != 'EMAIL_SENT' && MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()>0 && 
 emailAddress && subject && message) 
{       
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  sheet.getRange(i+1, 9).setValue('EMAIL_SENT');// Make sure the cell is 
 updated right away in case the script is interrupted
 }
 }
 }
```

Here is the link to the spreadsheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SOPiXhU3KWHpHyZEiDUSk8m5qzO5CyALWio6doQvJ4Q/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## A Simple Fix

Just had to change emailSent = rowData[25] rather than rowData[9]

```
function sendEmails()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var dataRange=sheet.getDataRange();
  var data=dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i=1;i<data.length;++i) 
  {
     var rowData = data[i];
     var emailAddress = rowData[1];
     var recipient = rowData[0];
     var message1 = rowData[3];
     var message2 = rowData[4];
     var message3 = rowData[5];
     var message4 = rowData[6];
     var message5 = rowData[7];
     var emailSent = rowData[25];//Change from 9 to 25
     var message = 'Hi ' + recipient + ',\n\n' + message1 + ' ' + message2 + ',\n\n' + message3 + ',\n' + message4 + ',\n' + message5;
     var subject = 'Medical Questionairre Check';
     var rdq=MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();

    if (!emailSent && rdq>0 && emailAddress && subject && message)
    {       
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message)
      //Logger.log('emailAddress: %s subject: %s message: %s emailSent: %s',emailAddress,subject,message,emailSent);
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 26).setValue('EMAIL_SENT');
     }
   }
}
```

The spreadsheet after execution:

[image]

Comment: I have marked yours as the answer as it is working, thank you.  However it regularly comes up with the error "exceeded maximum execution time" is this just because it is iterating through 1000 rows?  Thank you for your assistance on this and other projects.  They are all slowly coming together!

Comment: Just removed 500 rows from bottom and didn't get "exceeded max time warning" so guess that was it. again thank you.  Was having issues and took me ages to notice the difference between row 25 and then 26 for email sent, I assume due to 1 being array.